# Why parity exchanges right handed and left handed spinors

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, spinors, parity

Reading through David Tong lecture notes on QFT.

On pages 94, he shows the action of parity on spinors.  See below link:

[QFT notes by Tong](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf)

In (4.75) he confirms that parity exchanges right handed and left handed spinors for an arbitrary representation of the Clifford algebra. But this is unclear to me.

To prove he says:

**Under parity, rotations don't change sign. But boosts do flip sign.**

Again this isn't clear. We are talking about a discrete Lorentz transformation, i.e. parity, which is neither a rotation nor a boost. But why we are mixing them up?

Comment: This is e.g. explained in footnote 3 of my Phys.SE answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/28651/2451).

Comment: In physical terms this is because chirally dual spinors (right and left handed) are the spin-orthogonal, space inverted of each other. For details see also http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263047/ .